# CSS: Changing margins of child in parent container changes child's width?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand padding, margins and negative margins in CSS, and I created the below code to increase my understanding.

I tried adding a margin to my "row" class, and based on my basic knowledge about margins in CSS I expected the following to occur:

- Positive margin-left of 20px would push my div with class "row" 20px to the left.
- Negative margin-left of 20px would push my div with class "row" 20px to the right.

However, this is not what happens. Actually the following happens:

- Positive margin-left decreases the width of my div with class "row" with 20px to the left.
- Negative margin-left increases the width of my div with class "row" with 20px to the left.

Now I have a feeling this is because my div with class "row" is a child of the div with class "container". However, I do not understand why this behavior happens. I hope anyone can help!

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

.row {
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
}

.col { 
    background-color: blue;
    float: left; 
    width: 20%;
}

</style>
    <title>Margintest</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">  
        <div class = "col"> ok </div>
        <div class = "col"> ok </div>
        <div class = "col"> ok </div>
        <div class = "col"> ok </div>
        <div class = "col"> ok </div>
        <div class = "col"> ok </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is normal behaviour - without a width given to the element, all the negative margin does is move the left side 20 px to the left whilst leaving the right side in the same place.  If the element has a width given to it, then as the left side moves 20px to the left, it will also pull the right side with it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

It is not caused by the fact that the div is a child of another div, but by the fact that you're not setting a specific width to the `row` div.
Without a width specified, the width is `auto`, which means: use the width of the parent, subtracted by the width of the margins, paddings etc.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Great, thank you! This definitely clears things up. I did not know that the width: auto value subtracted the width of the margin/paddings in calculating its width. The outcome makes sense then!

Answer (score 0):

Margin is the space around the element. So

```
margin-left: 20px;
```

means "I want 20px of space on the left side of my element". So, the element is moved to the right.
The margin does not decrease the width of your element in general.

In your case it does. But only because your container is set to a fixed width of 200px. The row element tries to fill this space. So, without margin, it would also be 200px wide. If there is space between the row and the container (which size does not change), the row´s width is decreased.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

[image: Sorry for my bad drawing]

(Sorry for my bad drawing)

**Long answer:**

It seems you have some misunderstanding of margin. A margin gives the element a transparent space/area outside of its border.

In your example, the left border of the `row` is shown as the blue line (well, not all the way down). And the margin of the `row` move it right 20px.

You can learn more about margin and padding at here:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp